# .htaccess file and rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to create a .htaccess file and add the following rewrite rules to it:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

my virtual host setting in xampp server (Apache version 2.4.4) is:

```
<Directory  C:/vhosts>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot  C:/vhosts/phpcs5
    ServerName  phpcs5
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone suggest me how to write my .htaccess file? Sorry, if this question looks too ordinary for you; I am new to Apache mod_rewrite. Thank you.

It's giving error when I try to put those rules under

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /phpcs5

//rules//

</IfModule>
```

here is my .htaccess file that's giving error

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# Enable mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine On
CHAPTER 7 ■ SEARCH ENGINE OPTIMIZATION 192
# Specify the folder in which the application resides.
# Use / if the application is in the root.
RewriteBase /tshirtshop
# Rewrite to correct domain to avoid canonicalization problems
# RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite URLs ending in /index.php or /index.html to /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ .*/index\.(php|html?)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.(php|html?)$ $1 [R=301,L]
# Rewrite category pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Depart
mentId=$1&CategoryId=$2&Page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Cate
goryId=$2 [L]
# Rewrite department pages
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1&Pag
e=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?DepartmentId=$1 [L]
# Rewrite subpages of the home page
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?Page=$1 [L]
# Rewrite product details pages
RewriteRule ^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?ProductId=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Not really sure where your problem is. If you already got the directives, just put them either in a .htaccess file in the directory they should apply to, or stick them inside the VirtualHost container if they should apply to the whole host.

Comment: I have edited my post for more info

Comment: Just set the rules directly in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Please post us the whole (not just parts of it) file in which you placed the rules (unless XAMPP is still using a single configuration file, than please post complete sections at least), and the exact error message you get.